# Chrome like collapsible search bar (in java - swing)

Tags: java, swing, search, user-interface, google-chrome

Does anyone know how to write some code in java to simulate the behaviour of the collapsible search bar in Google Chrome i.e the search bar when you press Ctrl-F

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The SwingX project has a JXCollapsiblePane.  That should do what you want.

http://java.net/projects/swingx/